# how to create a scrollView in Flutter Flame

Tags: flutter, scrollview, flame

I need a listView for my Game. Is there a simple way to create one? There are no tutorials for such a feature and I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flame doesn't provide their own widgets for these things, we rely on Flutters excellent widget system.

So you create the widget directly in Flutter and then you either put your `GameWidget` in a stack (or similar) and use Flutter's own [Navigation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation) to move between the widgets, or you use [Flame's overlay system](https://flame-engine.org/docs/#/game?id=flutter-widgets-and-game-instances).

For using the overlays you add the overlays that you want to have accessible when you create the `GameWidget` and then you call `game.overlays.add` to render a specific widget, and `game.overlays.remove` to stop rendering it.

Comment: Are there any tutorials for this? I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Tutorials for how to create a ScrollView, or to use the Flame overlays API? For the latter there is information about it in the Flame docs (it is a pretty small api).

Comment: @spydon could you help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69328474/can-i-use-a-widget-as-a-actual-component-in-flutter-flame